# Importing CSV that has an extra row represented as new columns

Tags: python, pandas

As the title says, I'm attempting to import about 30 CSV files and combine into one. Each file has 15 of the 'correct' columns, with an additional 15 columns of only one row's worth of data. So, in total, each file appears to have 30 columns, but in reality there should only be 15 columns, and the second set of columns should just be appended to the bottom of my data as an extra row. For a smaller example, it looks something like this:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 5.87 6.12 5.50 4.98 2.87
2.50 3.50 5.66 5.23 2.11
1.12 9.99 1.15 5.44 3.12
```

I'm looking to take those 5 'extra' columns (which are really just one extra row) and move them to the bottom of my data, as another row, instead of appearing as 5 more columns.

Comment: I would do the string processing independent of the CSV. Load the data in using Python's normal text file libraries, insert the necessary break to make it conforming, and then use `io.StringIO` to read it into pandas

Comment: Okay, I might have misunderstood here. Is the bad row the first row in the file? It looks like you have a header + first row where somebody forgot to put a newline after the header.

Comment: @tdelaney That's also what I understood.

Comment: So the 1st row appears to have 30 columns, but columns 16-30 are just values that should have been a new row. The 1st row is the only row that appears like this. All other rows only have 15 values

Comment: ...and the first row is a header row - naming the column instead of providing values?

Comment: Correct, so the first row should only be 15 values, with column names. Instead, it's 30 values - the first 15 being the column names, the next 15 being the first set of 15 values. The small example I provided above is exactly how it appears

Comment: Sorry to be a pest, but, you want it written to the end of the file? Not as the first data row? And by "end of the file" should rows from all 30 botched csvs saved until the end of the final file, or just the end of writing a single file?

Comment: No problem at all, more than happy to elaborate. It doesn't really make a difference if those values are the first data row, or the last. I just want to make sure that they do get included as a row in my data, as my current solution is just ignoring them altogether (currently I'm only reading in the first 15 columns)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a botched header in each of the csv's. You can setup csv readers and a writer and at the start of each new input file, check whether the header is too long. You'll suppress the header after the first csv and insert the errant row as you go

```
output_csv = 'out.csv'
have_header = False

with open(output_csv, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as out_fp:
    writer = csv.writer(out_fp)
    for input_csv in input_csvs:
        with open(input_csv, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as in_fp:
            reader = csv.reader(in_fp)
            end_rows = []
            header = next(reader)
            # check for botched first line where some upstream
            # program can't get its newlines right
            if len(header) > 15:
                header = header[:15]
                first_row = header[15:]
            else:
                first_row = None
            if not have_header:
                writer.writerow(header)
                have_header = True
            if first_row:
                writer.writerow(first_row)
            write.writerows(reader)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would help.

```
data = pd.read_csv("text.csv")
data = data.iloc[:,:15].append(data.iloc[1,15:])
```

this will cut of the second 15 columns and append the first row in bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply build a one row dataframe from the last part of the columns index, append it to the dataframe, and only keep the relevant columns:

```
n = len(df.columns)/2
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([df.columns[n:].tolist()], columns=df.columns[:n]))[df.columns[:n]]
```